# Возможно ли скрывать данные в адресной строке, которые передаются методом GET

Tags: php, javascript, get

Например есть страница `music?pages=labels` я могу как то скрыть эту часть `?pages=labels`.

Comment: А зачем вам? Если пользователь захочет, он всё равно узнает точный адрес страницы. Или вы из эстетических соображений?

Comment: Плюс, вы лишаете этого самого пользователя возможности оставить закладку/поделиться ссылкой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно решить это подгрузкой контента через ajax, соответвсенно все клики обрабатывать яваскриптом

Comment: думаю это лучший выход! Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, если вы передаёте через GET, то параметры всегда будут в адресной строке, во-вторых, современные браузеры эти параметры стараются не отображать пока пользователь не кликнет на адресную строку, и в-третьих, не хотите показывать параметры - передавайте через POST.

Comment: @fori1ton, разве, кроме Оперы кто-то скрывает параметры?

Comment: ОК, с вторым пунктом я погорячился.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, Яндекс.Браузер вроде скрывает

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант можно переписывать URL в music/labels - на сервере снова преобразовывать в music?pages=labels. И кто там знает, что такое labels.